# Spring WebFlux; unit testing exception thrown in Mono.map()

Tags: junit, mockito, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, junit5

I have some code that returns `Mono<List<UserObject>>`.  The first thing I want to do is check the List is not empty, and if it is, throw a `NoUsersFoundException`.  My code looks like this:

```
IUserDao.java
Mono<List<UserAccount>> getUserProfiles(final Set<UserQueryFilter> filters,
                                       final Set<String> attributes);
```

```
GetUserAccount.java
public Mono<UserAccount> doGetUserAccount() {
    return userDao.getUserProfiles(filters, attributes)
                      .map(list -> {
                          if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
                              throw new NoUsersFoundException();
                           }
                           return list;
                       })
                       .map(this::removePermissions)
                       .map(this::removeDuplicates);
}
```

I want to write a unit test that will test that the `NoUsersFoundException` is thrown when `userDao.getUserProfiles(filters, attributes)` returns an empty list.  When I use `Mockito#when` with a `.thenReturn()`, the test will, as expected, return immediately once `userDao.getUserProfiles(...)` is called without continuing the flow into the `.map()` where the list is checked and exception thrown.

```
@Mock
private IUserDao userDao;

private UserPolicies userPolicies;

@BeforeEach
public void init() {

    userPolicies = new UserPolicies(Set.of("XYZ", USER_AFF, "123"),
                                           Set.of(TestUserConstants.ID, TestUserConstants.SUBSCRIPTION_LEVEL));
}

@Test
void shouldThrowExceptionIfNoUsersFound() {

    final Set<UserFilter> filters = new UserFilterBuilder().withId(ID)
                                                           .withSubscription(PREMIUM)
                                                           .build();

    when(userDao.getUserProfiles(filters, userPolicies.getUserAttributeIds()))
                    .thenReturn(Mono.just(Collections.emptyList()));

    testClass = new GetUserAccount(userDao,
                                   userPolicies,
                                   filters,
                                   userPolicies.getUserAttributeIds());

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> testClass.doGetUserAccount()).isInstanceOf(NoUsersFoundException.class);
}
```

I have tried `.thenAnswer()` but it essentially does the same thing as the method called is not a void:

```
userDao.getUserProfiles(filters, userPolicies.getUserAttributeIds()))
                .thenAnswer((Answer<Mono<List>>) invocationOnMock -> Mono.just(Collections.emptyList()));
```

I can't see how using `reactor.test.StepVerifier` would work for this case.

Comment: Could you share your full unit test? From this it's not clear where it goes wrong.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I've updated my question with the full unit test and some further code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont really understand what you are asking for, but we commonly dont "throw" exceptions in reactor. We return a `Mono#error` downstream, and different operators will react accordingly as the error travels downstream.

```java
public Mono<List<Foobar> fooBar(filters, attributes) {
    return daoObject.getUserProfiles(filters, attributes)
                      .map(list -> {
                          if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
                              // Return a mono#error
                              return Mono.error( ... );
                           }
                           return list;
                       })
}
```

And then test using the step verifier. With either `expectNext` or `expectError`.

```java
// Happy case
StepVerifier.create( 
    fooBar(filters, attributes)) 
    .expectNext( ... ) 
    .verify();

// Sad case
StepVerifier.create( 
    fooBar(filters, attributes)) 
    .expectError( ... ) 
    .verify();
```

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare.  This code doesn't compile for me, giving the error `Required type: Mono<List<Foobar>, Provided: Mono<Object>`

Comment: the above code does not compile because it is no written to be compiled. I have no idea how you have implemented, the above code, but you are returning a Mono<Object> somewhere, which my code doesn't. Without you actually updating your question with your code, its is completly impossible for me to know what you have done because as much as a wish i was, i am not a mind reader.

Comment: Apologies, I had made a typo.  I think this is working for me now fully, with the `StepVerifier`.